# docker swarm and private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I try to test docker swarm and private registry as a service without TLS: 1 manager and 2 worker. On manager:

```
docker service create --name registry --publish 5000:5000 registry:2
```

When trying to check on manager, with

```
curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
```

or

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000/v2/_catalog
```

curl just wait for ever (at least an hour). Same on worker1. but on worker 2 works ok!

```
 curl 127.0.0.1:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":[]}
```

Then on manager

```
docker service ps registry
ID            NAME        IMAGE       NODE                DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE         ERROR  PORTS
p6ngzdemfolu  registry.1  registry:2  worker2  Running        Running 14 hours ago
```

I can see, that registry is running on worker2. So you can make pull/push/queries only on worker where image is running!?

My version of docker is:
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

What's am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like overlay network bug, Try this: `sudo docker network create registry --driver overlay` then delete the service and recreate using `--network registry`

Comment: tryed, no success: "docker service rm registry" , "docker network create registry --driver overlay", "docker service create --network registry --name registry --publish 5000:5000 registry:2"

Comment: `sudo docker network ls` on the nodes that are not running registry, do you see the newly created overlay network there?

Comment: yeps, all seems the same on every node "pwbft95nc4ut        registry            overlay             swarm"

Comment: `docker service scale helloworld=3` then when scaling finished try  `docker service scale helloworld=1` and  test again. replace helloworld with actual service name/id

Comment: I tryed with registry. Scaled to 3 and back to 1. image is running after that on manager. now manager shows result ok and and also worker 1. Worker 2 does not, it says: curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:5000; Connection refused

Comment: Are there firewall rules inplace between the nodes? and did you try external ip using curl?

Comment: Good catch. Infact there is. manager & worker1 on aws/ec2 ans worker2 on google cloud. There is open ports on all: (tcp) 2377,7946, 4789 and also 5000 (should not - I think) + 7946 (udp)

Comment: verify your ports with https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/7233b7ecf14bc49eb47715bbeb2a2769 please, there is an aws section, and I think you are missing some udp

Comment: Thank's you are right! udp for 4789 is missing. I add it, but not working yet. It seems that there is some problem with aws. inbound rules are not updated on instance. I think I must reboot servers.

Comment: nope. I triplecheck ports and protocols. registry network exists and service using it - on google. When try to connect from aws, i get message: curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:5000; Connection refused

Comment: Try openning all the ports (wildcard) to and from all 3 instances and try again, to make sure its not a firewall issue.

Comment: i added tcp&udf:0-65535, should be all to all nodes, but there is no effect. message is the same

Comment: Probably not a firewall issue then

Comment: I'm still not sure. When container is on aws-server (manager or worker2), both can connect to it, but google cannot. Otherway, when on google, neither aws cannot connect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to myself:

I moved manager to google and add one more worker on scenegroup. between workers there is all needed ports open. So my combination is manager+worker on GCE, worker on AWS and worker on SCENE.

All seems to work ok, when AWS worker is drained. If AWS worker active, there is problems with swarm. My own decision is, that there is something between google & amazon.